# Differences between git add and git stage?

Tags: git, git-bash

I know that "git add [file(s)]", lets git to track (version control) specified list of file(s). But it seems we could use the same command instead of "git stage [file(s)]" which add file(s) to the list of nominated files for the next commit (snapshot). So what is the technical differences between functionality of "git add" and "git stage"? It is not rational to think about these two as git identical options/commands or consider "stage" as a redundant or non-necessary one.

Many thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any. As [the manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stage) says,

```
GIT-STAGE(1)                      Git Manual                      GIT-STAGE(1)

NAME
       git-stage - Add file contents to the staging area

SYNOPSIS
       git stage args...

DESCRIPTION
       This is a synonym for git-add(1). Please refer to the documentation of
       that command.

GIT
       Part of the git(1) suite

Git 2.20.1                        12/15/2018                      GIT-STAGE(1)
```

If you look at the source code – the [built-in command list in git.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git.c#L444) – you'll also see that they map to the same function and therefore are identical:

```
static struct cmd_struct commands[] = {
    { "add", cmd_add, RUN_SETUP | NEED_WORK_TREE },
    ...
    { "stage", cmd_add, RUN_SETUP | NEED_WORK_TREE },
    ...
};
```

(You can also look at the [cmd_add() function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/add.c#L386) itself, and verify that it does not check what name it has been called by.)